# Change Plotly scatter plot color

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am trying to visualize a 4-class dataset via plotly.

For the following code :
`fig = px.scatter_3d(df_pca, x='pca1', y='pca2', z='pca3', color = 'emotion')`

I get the below graph which is not convenient to understand because the "blue" and "purple" colors are "indiscernible".

So I would like to change the "purple" color to "yellow". Could you please advise how to do it in plotly? The documentation does not seem very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this `color_discrete_sequence` parameter in the documentation, perhaps it can help you https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#explicitly-constructing-a-color-sequence

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.bar(df, y="continent", x="pop", color="continent", orientation="h", hover_name="country",
             color_discrete_sequence=["red", "green", "blue", "goldenrod", "magenta"],
             title="Explicit color sequence"
            )

fig.show()
```

[image: Bar plot with discrete color sequence]